# How to throw with some printout in C++

Tags: c++

If I just simply use `throw some_string;` then I get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'`. How can I get some printout with the string value actually shown, for example, `terminate called after throwing 'This is wrong'`, or something similar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you should be throwing subclasses of [`std::exception.`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/exception/)  Most C++ implementations automatically print out the result of calling `exception::what()` if the exception is uncaught.

```
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("This is wrong");
}
```

With GCC, this outputs:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  This is wrong
Aborted
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add code somewhere to deal with the thrown object.  If you do nothing the program ends in calling abort and the result of that is implementation defined. The solution for you is to add a catch block somewhere in your code, for example in your main function.  Here's why

1. You can catch the object you threw and construct a meaningful error message.
2. The default behavior results in terminating the program immediately without unwinding the stack and cleaning up.  The object that is throw must be caught somewhere before main returns in order to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the exception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) try
{
   throw std::string("This is a test");
   return 0;
}
catch(const std::string &s)
{
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Interesting use of a function try-catch block.  I had forgotten about that. Note this results in an implicit return value from main, which means main will return 0, which is probably not what you want if you are reporting an error condition when exiting.

Comment: Actually I was trying to use the obscure form - but I just threw it around my standard template of main func - I did not think about the return value. I would assume that the value is undefined since the 'return 0;' should not be executed - right?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: The return value of 0 is not from the `return 0;`, it is due to the fact that leaving main without encountering a `return` statement is equivalent to returning 0.

Comment: @Mankarse Could you point me at the standard section that says that - I'd like to read up on it.

Comment: @AdrianCornish: `[basic.start.main]/5`

>If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`